# __repr__ with 2 lists with multiple items in the List

Tags: python, class

hopefully quick answer! Any direction of help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to prepare for my final exam.

This is how I would be calling the class:

```
    >>> Q = priorityQueue()
    >>> Q.insert("text",10)
    >>> Q.insert("hello", 18)
    >>> Q
    text 10, hello 18
```

So I have a class like:

```
    class priorityQueue():

          def __init__(self):
              self.items = []
              self.priorities = []

           def insert(self, x, p):
              self.items.append(x)
              self.priorities.append(p)

           #This is where I dont understand how to get it to return how it should.
           def __repr__(self):
               new = []
               for x in range(len(self.items)):
                   new.append(str(self.items[x])+ " " +str(self.priorities[x]))
               return [str(x) for x in new]
```

This will give me an error like:

```
      TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type list)
```

Thanks Stack!

Comment: You are returning a list from `__repr__()`, what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__repr__` function must return a `string`, but you're returning a `list`.
Maybe you want to change the `return` line to `return '\n'.join(new)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def __repr__(self):
    new = []
    for x in range(len(self.items)):
        new.append(str(self.items[x])+ " " +str(self.priorities[x]))
    return ','.join(new)
```

Basically you need to return the output in the desired output, which is a comma separated  string.